# blender fails to render certain tiles -- is there some threshold i've exceeded?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, artifacts, mantaflow

I've been exploring the quick smoke simulation in Blender 2.92.0 and I have a particular quick-flash explosion working quite nicely, except blender fails to render some tiles, leaving them gray in the PNG files it's creating like this:
[image]

I first started seeing these when I had my particles at the maximum **Normal Velocity** of 1000 m/s with the Smoke Domain's **Fire Reaction Speed** below 0.5.

I haven't been able to identify any consistency in the location of these tiles beyond this vague feeling that it's related to particle speed or heat. The tile locations change if I take any action causing the particles to be regenerated or if I re-bake the smoke domain. They do tend to be located right in the middle of the screen, which reinforces my feeling that it might be related to velocity.

**EDIT:** I have uploaded the blender file I'm having trouble with (quite simple and small) to blend-exchange. You can download it here --> [image]

**EDIT 2:** I rebuilt my test file from scratch, and it lacks this artifact. It would appear that the file is somehow corrupted. I can only imagine what a nightmare it would be if you had spent months building an elaborate blender project only to have it inexplicably corrupted somehow. If anyone has tips on how to repair or reset such a file, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with you exceeding some limit of your GPU (eg, memory) for the more complicated parts of the render. You could try rendering with CPU and see if that resolves the problem. Could it be that when you tried to replicate in another file that something was different? eg, subdivision set to a different level. If could be that the number of faces is below the threshold in the file you have recreated. In the rare instances where something is corrupted you can start a new file and the use the 'Append' option to import elements from your old file.